# How's quantum noise and fault-tolerance related to symplectic geometry and geometric quantization?

Tags: mathematics, noise, fault-tolerance

Gil Kalai [often speaks](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/symplectic-geometry-quantization-and-quantum-noise/) of the apparent connection between [symplectic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry), [geometric quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization), and [quantum noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_noise). He is known to describe one of his focus areas as:

> (...) properties and models of quantum noise which do not enable quantum fault tolerance believed to be crucial for building quantum computers.

I'm somewhat aware of the basic notions of symplectic geometry and geometric quantization, but could someone give me a basic outline of how this relates to quantum noise and fault tolerance?